# fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64' for 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

I am try to run a sample application. This application is for 32 bit machine. but i want to run it in 64 bit machine but i get this following error:

**AFE\AnyFirewallEngine\Unicode Debug\AfBenchmark.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'**

i use here two third party library 
1. Openssl-0.9.8e
2. boost

which is already build for 64 bit.

My compiler is  visual studio 2010

plz help me.................

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4364020/1064610

Comment: Can you clarify the "want" statement? Do you want to run a 32bit app on a 64bit OS (which means do nothing, btw), or do you want to *compile* your prior-built-32bit app *source code* to a 64bit *target* and run it on a 64bit OS?

Comment: Are you trying to build a 32-bit application which you'll run on a 64-bit machine? Or are you trying to build a 64-bit application? You cannot link 32-bit executables, libraries or DLLs with 64-bit executables, libraries or DLLs.

Comment: i want to build 32bit application on 64bit os

Comment: Then you need to use 32-bit builds of libraries, not 64-bit builds.

Comment: Ya thanx i change it and solve it :)

Answer (score 2):

in my case I had the same problem with `openssl 1.0.2d`:

```
fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
```

the problem was solved when I run `vcvars64.bat` insted of `vcvars32.bat`.
In VS15 it is at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat
```

then I was able to run `ms\do_win64a` and nmake -f `ms\nt.mak` with no problem

Answer (score 1):

You are obviously using at least [one other third party library](http://www.anyfirewallengine.com/), and the binary which you are trying to link is built for x86. You will have to find or produce an x64 binary of AFE instead.