# error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64' cannot solve

Tags: visual-c++, dll, shared-libraries, matlab-deployment

I am trying to integrate the C++ shared library generated from MATLAB deploytool. I have included all the necessary libraries and references. I get the error

error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

when I try to bulid. I changed the target machine type to machine x64. I am using MATLAB 64 bit. I also changed the settings in the configration manager setting active platform to x64 but also the error persist.

Any other solutions? And yes when I try to change my target machine in the linker to x86 I get the completely opposite error

error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'

Comment: Have a look at this answer [fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'][1] to see if it can help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3563756/723554

Answer (score 0):

It seems, included libraries using another libs, which compiled in X86