# Compiling OpenCV program and not requiring opencv Installed

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation

I have developed a C++ program that uses OpenCV. However, when I compile it and try running it into another computer it doesn't run unless I install OpenCV in it and set the environment path to it. Is there any way to tackle this and how?

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 and the propgram only runs in Windows (since Kinect SDK is also used with it). Thanks!

Comment: One option is to create an installer that copies the required dlls along with your application.

Comment: ^^ or just copy and paste them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **dynamic linking**, make sure to use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) (or a similar to tool) to identify which OpenCV DLLs you need to ship along with your executable (you don't need to install the entire OpenCV package).

That's something you don't have to deal with **static linking**: 
[Using static libraries instead of dynamic libraries in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16830842/176769)