# OpenCv Form Application Release

Tags: c++, forms, visual-studio, opencv

I wonder is it possible to build windows form application with opencv static library? I know how do this with console application (like in this thread [using static libraries instead of dynamic libraries in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830842/using-static-libraries-instead-of-dynamic-libraries-in-opencv) ), but when we use windows form we can't use MTd  Runtime Library (only MD) But when we use MD Runtime Library then we can't use .lib library, only .dll. Am i right? I hope that somebody can help me:)

Comment: native C++ project or CLR project? First you need figure this out.

Comment: CLR project in visual-studio 2013

Answer (score 0):

You're probably confusing a number of things. Your C++ application needs a Microsoft C++ library and an OpenCV library. These are rather independent.

Microsofts C++ library comes in 4 variants, not two. The choice between static and dynamic is independent from the choice debug/release. That's why you have `/MD, /MT, /MDd, /MTd`.

The OpenCV library also has 4 variants, but you probably do not need the debug variants.

Comment: ok everything you said is true, but I wondrer is it possible to build clr project which use openCv?:)