# Installing ggplot for Python

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-ggplot

I've had a frustrating time installing the pandas and ggplot packages for Python.  I completely unistalled two old versions of Python and installed Canopy (Enthought Python Distribution Free), because it came 'out of the box' with several of ggplot's dependencies.

When I try 'pip install ggplot', I get the following error:
python27.lib(python27.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'

I have a 64 bit Windows 7 OS.  I installed 64 bit Canopy.  Somewhere I read that Python requires Visual Studio 2008 to be installed.  That is hard to track down, so I believe I ended up with a 32 bit version of VS 2008.

Is 32 bit Visual Studio causing this error?  Do I really need 2008?  (The oldest the Visual Studio website offers is Visual C++ 2010, but its not clear if I would receive 32 bit or 64 bit.)

If you answer, please assume I know very little about what I'm doing.

I've read answers to questions with the same error code, but they are a bit over my head.
[fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563756/fatal-error-lnk1112-module-machine-type-x64-conflicts-with-target-machine-typ)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is still an issue for others, but I've been able to resolve this by:

Opening Canopy's Package Manager, checking that the package isn't there.
From the main 'Welcome to Canopy' window, select 'Tools' and 'Canopy Command Prompt'.

The

```
pip install ggplot
```

then worked correctly (with a warning message, but still installed OK).

Note that the ggplot package does not show in the list of packages within the Canopy Package Manager, but can be found if you got into the Canopy Command Prompt and type

```
pip list
```

... hope this helps!

Reference from Enthought support:
https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469690-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-User-Python-from-the-OS-command-line

Answer (score 0):

I have some issues installing it on my old python version
It works perfectly with Anaconda using:

```
pip install ggplot
```

And don't forget that ggplot requires patsy http://patsy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html#installation