# Building Pin Tools (from Intel) through Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I downloaded Pin from Intel and while reading their manual from [Intel Pin User Manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/65163/Pin/html/)  and started working on it by first Building the Example Tools. But while building itself i got the problem :

```
cl /nologo /DTARGET_WINDOWS /DFUND_TC_HOSTOS=FUND_OS_WINDOWS /DFUND_TC_TARGETOS=
FUND_OS_WINDOWS /MD /EHa /Gy- /DTARGET_IA32E /DHOST_IA32E /DFUND_TC_TARGETCPU=FU
ND_CPU_INTEL64 /DFUND_TC_HOSTCPU=FUND_CPU_INTEL64  /O2  /Feobj-intel64/fibonacci
.exe fibonacci.cpp /link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /OPT:REF
fibonacci.cpp
cl /nologo /DTARGET_WINDOWS /DFUND_TC_HOSTOS=FUND_OS_WINDOWS /DFUND_TC_TARGETOS=
FUND_OS_WINDOWS /MD /EHa /Gy- /DTARGET_IA32E /DHOST_IA32E /DFUND_TC_TARGETCPU=FU
ND_CPU_INTEL64 /DFUND_TC_HOSTCPU=FUND_CPU_INTEL64  /O2  /Feobj-intel64/little_ma
lloc.exe little_malloc.c /link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /OPT:REF
little_malloc.c
cl /nologo /DTARGET_WINDOWS /DFUND_TC_HOSTOS=FUND_OS_WINDOWS /DFUND_TC_TARGETOS=
FUND_OS_WINDOWS /MD /EHa /Gy- /DTARGET_IA32E /DHOST_IA32E /DFUND_TC_TARGETCPU=FU
ND_CPU_INTEL64 /DFUND_TC_HOSTCPU=FUND_CPU_INTEL64  /O2  /Feobj-intel64/thread_ap
p.exe thread_win.c /link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /OPT:REF
thread_win.c
cl /nologo /DTARGET_WINDOWS /DFUND_TC_HOSTOS=FUND_OS_WINDOWS /DFUND_TC_TARGETOS=
FUND_OS_WINDOWS /MD /EHa /Gy- /DTARGET_IA32E /DHOST_IA32E /DFUND_TC_TARGETCPU=FU
ND_CPU_INTEL64 /DFUND_TC_HOSTCPU=FUND_CPU_INTEL64  /Od  /Feobj-intel64/divide_by
_zero.exe divide_by_zero_windows.c /link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /OPT:NOREF
divide_by_zero_windows.c
cl /MT /EHs- /EHa- /wd4530 /DTARGET_WINDOWS /DBIGARRAY_MULTIPLIER=1 /D_CRT_SECUR
E_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0 /nologo /Gy /DTARGET_IA32E /DHOST_IA32E  /I../../
../source/include/pin /I../../../source/include/pin/gen /I../../../extras/compon
ents/include /I../../../extras/xed2-intel64/include /I../../../source/tools/Inst
Lib /O2  /c /Foobj-intel64/inscount0.obj inscount0.cpp
inscount0.cpp
link /DLL /EXPORT:main /NODEFAULTLIB /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /MACHINE:x64 /ENTRY
:Ptrace_DllMainCRTStartup /BASE:0xC5000000 /OPT:REF  /out:obj-intel64/inscount0.
dll obj-intel64/inscount0.obj  /LIBPATH:../../../intel64/lib /LIBPATH:../../../i
ntel64/lib-ext /LIBPATH:../../../extras/xed2-intel64/lib pin.lib libxed.lib libc
pmt.lib libcmt.lib pinvm.lib kernel32.lib ntdll-64.lib
obj-intel64/inscount0.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' confl
icts with target machine type 'x64'
../../../source/tools/Config/makefile.default.rules:165: recipe for target 'obj-
intel64/inscount0.dll' failed
make: *** [obj-intel64/inscount0.dll] Error 88
```

Again while trying to build only fibonacci.dll as **make fibonacci.test** I got following error:

```
make -C ../../../source/tools/Utils dir obj-intel64/cp-pin.exe
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/d/Pin/pin-2.13-62141-msvc8-windows/source
/tools/Utils'
mkdir -p obj-intel64/
cl /nologo /DTARGET_WINDOWS /DFUND_TC_HOSTOS=FUND_OS_WINDOWS /DFUND_TC_TARGETOS=
FUND_OS_WINDOWS /MD /EHa /Gy- /DTARGET_IA32E /DHOST_IA32E /DFUND_TC_TARGETCPU=FU
ND_CPU_INTEL64 /DFUND_TC_HOSTCPU=FUND_CPU_INTEL64  /O2  /Feobj-intel64/cp-pin.ex
e cp-pin.cpp /link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /OPT:REF
cp-pin.cpp
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/d/Pin/pin-2.13-62141-msvc8-windows/source/
tools/Utils'
cl /MT /EHs- /EHa- /wd4530 /DTARGET_WINDOWS /DBIGARRAY_MULTIPLIER=1 /D_CRT_SECUR
E_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0 /nologo /Gy /DTARGET_IA32E /DHOST_IA32E  /I../../
../source/include/pin /I../../../source/include/pin/gen /I../../../extras/compon
ents/include /I../../../extras/xed2-intel64/include /I../../../source/tools/Inst
Lib /O2  /c /Foobj-intel64/fibonacci.obj fibonacci.cpp
fibonacci.cpp
link /DLL /EXPORT:main /NODEFAULTLIB /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /MACHINE:x64 /ENTRY
:Ptrace_DllMainCRTStartup /BASE:0xC5000000 /OPT:REF  /out:obj-intel64/fibonacci.
dll obj-intel64/fibonacci.obj  /LIBPATH:../../../intel64/lib /LIBPATH:../../../i
ntel64/lib-ext /LIBPATH:../../../extras/xed2-intel64/lib pin.lib libxed.lib libc
pmt.lib libcmt.lib pinvm.lib kernel32.lib ntdll-64.lib
obj-intel64/fibonacci.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' confl
icts with target machine type 'x64'
../../../source/tools/Config/makefile.default.rules:165: recipe for target 'obj-
intel64/fibonacci.dll' failed
make: *** [obj-intel64/fibonacci.dll] Error 88
```

Can anybody please let me know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Important part: **fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' confl
icts with target machine type 'x64'**. So, similar question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563756/fatal-error-lnk1112-module-machine-type-x64-conflicts-with-target-machine-typ

Comment: Yes, I red that but since the project is having its Makefile and do command **make all** for building as said in the user manual i am having problem of changing configurations.