# 'LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'

Tags: opencv, highgui

I am using visual studio 2012.i got the error

```
LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type
'X86'highgui248d.lib(opencv_highgui248d.dll)' while building a win32 
console application.
```

I have tried modifying the property to match with my open_cv application requirement.

Comment: You are running a 64 bit setup in 32 bit os

Comment: Try changing Project -> Properties -> Platform

Comment: possible duplicate of [fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563756/fatal-error-lnk1112-module-machine-type-x64-conflicts-with-target-machine-typ)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer for your issue. Probably you need to change the platform in Build configuration manager
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4364020/3724463

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this annoying problem, just follow steps below:

1. In your Project Properties -> VC++ Directories -> **Library Directories** check that you have included **only x64 build path** if not please remove the x86 build path (something like this: C:\opencv2413\build\x64\vc12\lib) make changes according to extraction path of OpenCV in your system.
2. In your Project Properties -> Linker -> General -> **Additional Library Directories** check that it is set to x64 and **not x86** like this ($(OPENCV_BUILD)\x64\vc12\lib).
3. If you have added a property sheet apply above steps to same.
4. **Delete** Release|Win32 and Debug|Win32 (or Release|X86 and Debug|X86) in property Manager.
5. Build your project using Release or Debug x64.

If this doesn't work please let me know, I would be glad to help.