# compiling qcad lnk1112 module machine type 'x64' conflict with target machine type 'x86'

Tags: nmake, qcad

I am trying to compile QCAD. I have followed these steps: https://www.qcad.org/en/component/content/article/78-qcad/111-qcad-compilation-from-sources

I'm using the exact versions that are mentionned

When I run "nmake release" I get this error: "lnk1112 module machine type 'x64' conflict with target machine type 'x86'"

I have tried every single solution available on the internet. Most of them include changing some settings in the VS project and I don't think its possible to build qcad from VS.

I'm running windows 10 on a surface pro.

Comment: change target machine type to "x64"

Comment: [fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3563756/995714), ['LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25936688/995714), [How to resolve the module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64' Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31595869/995714)