# Link error C1905 while compiling for 64bit using VS2013

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I've a VC++ code (VS2013) which is compiling perfectly fine in 32 bit. But when I try to compile the same code in 64bit, I'm getting the below linker error.

```
1>LINK : fatal error C1905: Front end and back end not compatible (must target same processor).
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1257: code generation failed
```

I referred the links ::
[Stackoverflow-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563756/fatal-error-lnk1112-module-machine-type-x64-conflicts-with-target-machine-typ)

**Can I please get help to solve this issue and the code compiled for 64 bit.**
Unable to attach the code snippet here because, it's a very big code base.

Comment: What are you specifying for target machine architecture?  Make sure you are not mixing up the different 64 bit architecture types for your build.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot link 32-bit (x86) code with 64-bit (x64) code in the same executable or DLL. That means using 64-bit only versions of all your static libraries, import libraries, and DLLs. It means ensuring that every project in your solution is building with the x64 configuration.

See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/12/16/windows-x64.aspx) for a number of articles and presentations on 64-bit native programming.

Answer (score 0):

For x64 build:

Sometimes this will happen with an old project that is converted to a new version (e.g.: VC 2013 -> VC 2015).

Insert this line to all of your *.vcxproj :

```
<PreferredToolArchitecture>x64</PreferredToolArchitecture>
```

In the entry :

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
....
</PropertyGroup>
```

This will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of scouring all my objs, libs, and configurations, I tried turning my MSBuild verbosity setting up to Diagnostic level (under Tools / Options / Projects and Solutions / Build And Run in VS). This listed all the .lib's being used by the linker and I was able to find an x86 lib which was being pulled in by a `#pragma comment(lib, "foo.lib")`.

Not sure why the list of libs is not in one of the .tlog files.