# Boost can not find lib

Tags: c++, windows, boost

I'm interrested in unit test so i decided to install boost to make some unit tests included in that libraries.

First I've installed this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.57.0/
Then I've changed paths in my VS2013 to find headers and libs(libs at linker options).
Then I had a problemem with x64 machine, so I did that: [fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563756/fatal-error-lnk1112-module-machine-type-x64-conflicts-with-target-machine-typ)

And right now I got a windows-massage, after compilation when program is about to run, which sounds like: It's not possible to run a program, becouse in that computer it is not able to find boost_unit_test_framework-vc120-mt-1_57.dll. Try to reinstal program, to repair that problem.

But I got that file in my C:\lib\boost_1_57_0\lib64-msvc-12.0 catalog.

what can I do?

Comment: Add `C:\lib\boost_1_57_0\lib64-msvc-12.0` to your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I did it. 
I've created C:\lib\boost_1_57_0\lib64-msvc-12.0 named boost_lib
and also C:\lib\boost_1_57_0\ named boost

Comment: _"I did it"_ You did what actually? You have added this directory to `PATH` already, and it's still not found, when you're running your program?

Comment: I've added boost to my Path enviroment variable:
http://i60.tinypic.com/dmdv20.png
biblioteki means libs.

Comment: You need to specify the directory in `PATH` where this `.dll` file can be found. I'm talking about `PATH` not those other variables you show!

Comment: Yea, but this .dll is exactly in C:\biblioteki\boost_1_57_0\lib64-msvc-12.0
So (if I understand you well) I've specified directory in Path where this .dll can be found. (Path named Boost_lib_1_57_0pro).

em I wrong?

Comment: You should just add this directory literally to `PATH` (without using a different environment variable), `PATH` might be established, before these other variables are set.

Comment: OMG. I guess I understand you now. w8 a minute

Comment: U meant that? http://i61.tinypic.com/20utwn7.png

Comment: Yes of course. What's so hard to get when I write `PATH`?

Comment: I forgot that there is a variable called Path. My bad, sorry ;)
It's working, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make the system to find a `.dll` file at runtime of a program, you need to add the directory where the `.dll` is located to the `PATH` environment variable. E.g. from the console (before running a program)

```
C:\Users\XYZ> set PATH="%PATH%;c:\directory_of_dll"
```