# CPLEX Concert Technology using C++ in Visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, cplex

I am a beginner in C++. I would like to use C++/Concert technology to code an optimization model. I read some tutorials to set up `CPLEX Concert` with C++ on Windows. I tried both Release and Debug modes. Finally I settled with the Debug mode. My computer has a 64-bit OS, the installed Cplex version is 12.6.1. I am using Visual Studio 2013. To build solution, I selected Debug in the Active Solution and x64 for the new platform. After compiling, I faced with the following error:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/459us.png]))".

The code is not mine, it is from tutorial file [here](http://people.tamu.edu/~bans1571/CPLEXConcertTutorial/) pages 8-9.

```
error C2018: unknown character '0x3'
```

Can anyone help me to fix this error?

Comment: Can you post the code fragment here or at least upload a decent picture? right now I see nothing but bunch of pixels.

Comment: Thank you Serge! The code is not mine! I just use the example of one tutorial:

Comment: @Serge, I changed the question and you can see the source program in the second link as well as the picture of the error that I have in the second one. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Cplex is 32-bit application so you should change `x64` to `x86` in the field next to `Debug` in the VS panel.

Comment: I changed but still I have this error: "fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'X64'".

Comment: In the following link, they completely explained the steps, however I checked the steps and could not overcome it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563756/fatal-error-lnk1112-module-machine-type-x64-conflicts-with-target-machine-typ .In linker the libraries that I added are as follows, do you think there is something wrong on these libraries?    C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1261\cplex\lib\x86_windows_vs2013\stat_mdd; C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1261\concert\lib\x86_windows_vs2013\stat_mdd

Answer (score 0):

On page **7/20, step II.(e)**, the authors of the document advise to link with the cplex library: `cplex121.lib`, since they were using CPLEX 12.1. Please notice you should be entering `cplex1261.lib` instead. Also, there's no need to indicate the full path to the libraries there, you could use `cplex1261.lib`, `concert.lib` and `ilocplex.lib` instead.

I recommend you [this tutorial](http://www.leandro-coelho.com/how-to-configure-ms-visual-studio-to-use-ibm-cplex-concert/) on how to setup the C++ with CPLEX link, is simple and quite straightforward: