# machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, 64-bit

So I get this error when I select Debug and Win32 for my configuration but the software itself came with this settings:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Category Source Suppression State Tool
Error LNK1112 module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86' renderdoc 

C:\Users\mona\playing-for-data\renderdoc\renderdoc\IlmImf.lib(IlmImf.dll) 1 fatal Build
```

And when I build with x64 and Debug I get this error:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Category Source Suppression State Tool
Error LNK1181 cannot open input file 'C:\Users\mona\playing-for-data\renderdoc\renderdoc\driver\shaders\spirv\x64\Debug\PpTokens.obj' renderdoc C:\Users\mona\playing-for-data\renderdoc\renderdoc\LINK 1 fatal Build
```

I am not sure how this could be fixed. My assumption is Win32 Debug should also work on a 64 bit machine as well.

Here's the original code: https://bitbucket.org/visinf/projects-2016-playing-for-data

[image]

Could having built the OpenEXR with x64 Visual Studio have caused this using CMake?
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563756/fatal-error-lnk1112-module-machine-type-x64-conflicts-with-target-machine-typ)

Comment: you try using x64 `IlmImf.lib` when build x86 exe. you need search for all `IlmImf.lib` files - where is x64 and x86 lib versions. you need use path to x86 version of `IlmImf.lib` in build x86 exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to make stuff with Cmake with x64 option and also build them in VS2015 using x64 release.