# LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86' - opencv build

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2015

I have been trying to install Opencv in Windows, according to this [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html). I assume that the [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html) helps in installation of opencv for both c++ and python.

More details about my system:

```
    ** Visual studio - 15.9.6
    ** Windows 10- 64 bit

    ** Complete error - 1>------ Build started: Project: gen_opencv_python_source, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
    2>------ Build started: Project: opencv_python3, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
    2>python36.lib(python36.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
    2>Done building project "opencv_python3.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

A popular [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563756/fatal-error-lnk1112-module-machine-type-x64-conflicts-with-target-machine-typ) for this question, suggested the following steps :

```
    Check your properties options in your linker settings at: Properties > 
   Configuration Properties > Linker > Advanced > Target Machine. Select 
   MachineX64 if you are targeting a 64 bit build, or MachineX86 if you are 
   making a 32 bit build.
```

From the image below, however, I do not have any other option other than Win32. And Looks like  VSdoesn'thave a 64 bit release. How do I resolve this issue and what am I missing from the previous answer? Apologies if the issue is trivial.

[image]

**Update**

the python version I am using is 3.6.5 64 bit. could this be the issue, with VS being 32 bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you did select Visual Studio version in CMake (step 7.4.a) then it need select a 64 bit compiler: "Visual Studio 15 64" instead "Visual Studio 15".

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!